# AGGrid Infinite Scroll Table not showing up when integrated with React App

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

**Problem Statement:-**

I am trying to integrate AGGrid react component to display a infinite scroll mechanism but for some reason, the table is not getting display and instead of that only one line is showing up.

**Situation when it works:-**

So, if I create the Grid component directly inside my index.js file and add it to the root, it works fine but as soon as I export it from another file, the component doesn't render.

I am sure, I am missing something small here, anything pointers or solutions will be of great help.

I am adding all the code the way, I am importing.

**App.js**

```
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";

const App = () => {
  const containerStyle = useMemo(() => ({ width: "100", height: "100" }), []);
  const gridStyle = useMemo(() => ({ height: "50", width: "50" }), []);

  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
    // this row shows the row index, doesn't use any data from the row
    {
      headerName: "ID",
      maxWidth: 100,
      // it is important to have node.id here, so that when the id changes (which happens
      // when the row is loaded) then the cell is refreshed.
      valueGetter: "node.id",
      cellRenderer: (props) => {
        if (props.value !== undefined) {
          return props.value;
        } else {
          return (
            <img src="https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/loading.gif" />
          );
        }
      }
    },
    { field: "athlete", minWidth: 150 },
    { field: "age" },
    { field: "country", minWidth: 150 },
    { field: "year" },
    { field: "date", minWidth: 150 },
    { field: "sport", minWidth: 150 },
    { field: "gold" },
    { field: "silver" },
    { field: "bronze" },
    { field: "total" }
  ]);
  const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      flex: 1,
      resizable: true,
      minWidth: 100
    };
  }, []);

  const onGridReady = useCallback(async (params) => {
    const dataSource = {
      rowCount: undefined,
      getRows: async (params) => {
        console.log("asking for " + params.startRow + " to " + params.endRow);
        // At this point in your code, you would call the server.
        // To make the demo look real, wait for 500ms before returning
        let resp = await fetch(
          "https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json"
        );
        let data = await resp.json();
        const rowsThisPage = data.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
        // if on or after the last page, work out the last row.
        let lastRow = -1;
        if (rowsThisPage.length <= params.endRow) {
          lastRow = rowsThisPage.length;
        }
        // call the success callback
        params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
      }
    };
    params.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
  });

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <div style={gridStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine">
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          rowBuffer={0}
          rowSelection={"multiple"}
          rowModelType={"infinite"}
          cacheBlockSize={100}
          cacheOverflowSize={2}
          maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests={1}
          infiniteInitialRowCount={1000}
          maxBlocksInCache={10}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ag-grid-packages",
  "description": "NOTE: This package.json file is solely used by Plunker to look up type definitions.",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "18",
    "@types/react-dom": "18",
    "ag-grid-community": "^30.2.1",
    "ag-grid-react": "^30.2.1",
    "axios": "1.6.0",
    "react": "18",
    "react-dom": "18"
  }
}
```

Thanks again :)

**Situation when it works:-**

So, if I create the Grid component directly inside my index.js file and add it to the root, it works fine but as soon as I export it from another file, the component doesn't render.

**Working Scenario:-**

A table should be rendered along with infinite scrolling.